# Map function loops and gives error - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created tabs that are created by clicking on a menu item. After that I wanted the closing "X" to only appear when hovering over the `<li>` parent.

I think it's a map problem that has not yet been created when I try to paint the "X" hover, but I do not know how to fix it. Why do I get this error? `` Can not update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. ``

```
class LiTabs extends Component{
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);

        ["showCloseTabs",].forEach((method) => {
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
        });

        this.state = {
            closeTabs: false,
        };
    }

    showCloseTabs(e){
        this.setState({
            closeTabs : true, 
        })
        console.log(e);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <>
            {this.props.tabsLi.map((value, index) =>
                <li key={index} onMouseOver={this.showCloseTabs(this)}>
                    <span>{value}</span>
                    <div onClick={this.props.removeTab.bind(this, value, index)} >
                        {this.state.closeTabs === true && (
                            <Icon icon="cerrar" className='ico-cerrar'/>
                        )}
                    </div>
                </li>
            )}         
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use **CSS** to show/hide the X button. Do not use `onMouseOver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.showCloseTabs(this)` is a function call in JavaScript, this means that function is called when `render` method is called.

This function is doing a `setState` which leads to the error:

> Can not update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state.

What needs to be passed to `onMouseOver` or `onClick` are references to the functions. In case of `showCloseTabs`, that is going to be:

```
onMouseOver={this.showCloseTabs}
```

If you need to pass arguments:

```
onMouseOver={(e) => this.showCloseTabs(e)}
```

Also binding the method in `render` creates new functions very time render is called. Instead you can bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.onMouseOver = this.onMouseOver.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Och, I see we both missed it, there is already constructor binding :)

Comment: @Icepickle true, missed that

Comment: @Boy With Silver Wings Thank you. I had forgotten that you can use the key functions for this

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a bind on `this.showCloseTabs(this)` which causes it to call it directly

To be fair, you should probably just remove the `(this)` all together there though (so even not have the bind in the mapping function)

```
{this.props.tabsLi.map((value, index) =>
    <li key={index} onMouseOver={this.showCloseTabs.bind(this)}>
        <span>{value}</span>
        <div onClick={this.props.removeTab.bind(this, value, index)} >
            {this.state.closeTabs === true && (
                <Icon icon="cerrar" className='ico-cerrar'/>
            )}
        </div>
    </li>
)}
```

To use class properties, you can change the declaration of your method like

```
showCloseTabs = (e) => { /* ... */ }
```

In both cases, you could then change the `onMouseOver` property to be

```
onMouseOver={this.showCloseTabs}
```

And be done with it :)